# Meaning of array declaration in Assembly

Tags: assembly, masm

Does anyone know what this line of code does? 
`vet db 10, ?, 10 dup ('$')`

I know that `vet db 10 dup (?)` creates an unitialized array, but that one?

Comment: It creates a byte array with the values `10d`,unspecified,`$`,`$`,`$`,`$`,`$`,`$`,`$`,`$`,`$`,`$`. That's all.

Comment: In practice, any `?` will end up as `0` when its mixed with non-`?` values in the same declaration.  And normally even a whole `10 dup(?)` array will be zeroed, in the BSS, but it's possible in bootloader code or something that such arrays might actually start with garbage.  But if the bytes before and after are initialized, the `?` is just going to be loaded from the file along with them, so it's whatever the assembler puts there (which is `0`).  This whole "uninitialized" `?` thing is more confusing than it needs to be, most of the time.

Comment: @PeterCordes = whether data is initialized to zero in BSS depends on assembler and linker. At least in the case of Microsoft 16 bit toolsets, it's uninitialized. In some cases in .data segment, I've seen cases where ... db  xxx dup (?) ended up with bits of source code, where the assembler just grabbed whatever was in memory to fill in the data.

Comment: @rcgldr: Oh, interesting, I hadn't thought of assemblers themselves copying uninitialized memory while assembling a `dup(?)` into non-BSS.   Other than that, yeah I ran out of room in one comment. Under all modern OSes, the BSS is zereod, so it's only in bootloaders / 16-bit code (where there's no kernel or it doesn't care about information leaks) that you ever get pages / bytes of random garbage for the BSS. Your assembler-garbage case certainly reinforces my feeling that you should never use `?` outside of the BSS; you might as well set any bytes that are going to be part of the object file.

Comment: I'm wondering if "vet" is being used for input, DOS INT 21H, AH = 0AH, but in that case it would make more sense to be `vet db 10, ? , 10 dup(?) `.

Comment: `db 10, ?, 10 dup ('$')` can be seen as three separate "db" directives: `db 10`, `db ?` and `db 10 dup ('$')`, where "`10 dup ('$')`" uses `dup` directive to create 10 times value `'$'` (36). So you will end with 12 bytes defined: 10, 0, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36  (the ? will turn into zero in this case as it is preceded and followed by hard-defined values, so it's easier for assembler to just fill it up as zero, for truly uninitialized memory space the `?` part would have to aim into some uninitialized section) - this is highly likely buffer for DOS 21h,0Ah service.